# createSlice: Redux store access differs between reducers and selectors?

Tags: redux

when using createSlice, I can give the slice a name, eg: 'person'. Within reducer code, store refers obviously to the 'person' part of the whole redux store (provided that I used the proper configureStore setup). So I can say store.firstName = 'Bernhad'; That's fine.

in selectors, things seem to be sligthly different: store is bound to the (whole?) redux store. So I have to code 'firstNameSelector = (store) => store.person.firstName;'

I think this is quite asymetric - one time having to use store.person, the other time just store - and I wonder: WHY IS THIS SO?

Any explanation highly appreciated!
Bernhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slice is that: a "part" of your state, that works on it's own. It does not know anything exists outside of it. You could mount it at different positions in your store or even in other stores and it would still behave exactly the same.

Selectors are a different thing. With a selector you look from the outside perspective at the **whole store** and select out those values you need. Within that selector you might want to access multiple slices to derive a value, so you'd always look at "the whole".

Comment: So the selector is a place to deliberatly add coupling between slices for the benefit of "global data access". OK, this I understand. Personally, I would like to keep my components as close to a single slice as possible :-) But thank you anyway.

Comment: Your components should be close to what you want to display while your slices should be close to your data structures. There could be (and often is) overlap, but do not put your component state in slices. Component state belongs into local component state, not into global redux state.